# Avoiding a two step insert in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Let's say I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
P_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
CompoundKey varchar(255) NOT NULL,
)
```

CompoundKey is a string with the primary key P_Id concatenated to the end, like Foo00000001 which comes from "Foo" + 00000001. At the moment, entries insertions into this table happen in 2 steps.

1. Insert a dummy record with a place holder string for CompoundKey.
2. Update the CompoundKey with the column with the generated compound key.

I'm looking for a way to avoid the 2nd update entirely and do it all with one insert statement. Is this possible? I'm using MS SQL Server 2005.

p.s. I agree that this is not the most sensible schema in the world, and this schema will be refactored (and properly normalized) but I'm unable to make changes to the schema for now.

Comment: Why would you apply formating to a key? This can be generated on the fly any time it is needed.

Comment: I personally wouldn't. This is a database schema that I've inherited, and as such I need to improve it in stages without breaking too much existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your could use a computed column; change the schema to read:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
P_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
CompoundKeyPrefix varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CompoundKey AS CompoundKeyPrefix + CAST(P_Id AS VARCHAR(10))
)
```

This way, SQL Server will automagically give you your compound key in a new column, and will automatically maintain it for you. You may also want to look into the `PERSIST` keyword for computed columns which will cause SQL Server to materialise the value in the data files rather than having to compute it on the fly. You can also add an index against the column should you so wish.

Comment: +1 this is probably the *safest* way to do it, but doesn't actually eliminate the `UPDATE`, it just abstracts it from the user.

Comment: This looks like the best answer. I'll try changing the schema when I'm at work tomorrow. Will changing the schema preserve the existing data in the table?

Comment: Just use ALTER TABLE instead: `ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD RealCompoundKey AS .....` and your data will remain intact.

Answer (score 1):

A [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) would easily accomplish this

Comment: A trigger **does not** eliminate the `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` the user just doesn't actually execute the `UPDATE` himself

Comment: +1  @Matthew PK In an insert trigger, you can alter the record that is being inserted. You don't need to do that with an update and it will be faster and more effecient. Not to mention, hidden from all processes that need to insert records.

Comment: @GolezTrol though it happens via a trigger, and is transparent to you, an `UPDATE` transaction has occurred.

Comment: It would not. The trigger is executed at the moment the record *is being* created. You can edit the values that are *to be* inserted. The record doesn't even exist in the database yet. A real update statement would fail.

Comment: @GolezTrol the PK *does not exist* until it's generated at `INSERT` time.

Comment: Not even in the after trigger?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible.
The "next ID" doesn't *exist* and thus cannot be read to fulfill the `UPDATE` until the row is inserted.

Now, if you were sourcing your autonumbers from somwhere else you could, but I don't think that's a good answer to your question.

Even if you want to use triggers, an `UPDATE` is still executed even if *you* don't manually execute it.
You can *obscure* the population of the CompoundKey, but at the end of the day it's still going to be an `UPDATE`

I think your safest bet is just to make sure the `UPDATE` is in the same transaction as the `INSERT` or use a trigger. But, for the academic argument of it, an `UPDATE` still occurs.

Comment: This is not possible. Which is why it should be avoided in the first place.

Comment: @JeffO I don't follow your comment... are you agreeing with me or refuting something I said?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) if you end up using two inserts, you must use transaction! Otherwise other processes may see the database in inconsistent state (i.e. seeing record without CompoundKey).

2) I would refrain from trying to paste the Id to the end of CompoundKey in transaction, trigger etc. It is much cleaner to do it at the output if you need it, e.g. in queries (`select concat(CompoundKey, Id) as CompoundKeyId ...`). If you need it as a foreign key in other tables, just use the pair (CompoundKey, Id).

Comment: Don't worry, they are already in a transaction. That was one of the changes I made when I inherited the code. Your 2nd option is exactly how I would do it when I get the opportunity to change the schema, but I can't do it just yet.

Comment: Yes @Philip, I see - maintaining old code of other people can be sometimes tricky.